# How to update an ImageField in Django

Tags: django, image, field, edit

I am making a website and would like to make it possible for each user to upload and update his own profile picture.

The update-profile template loads perfectly fine. I can update all the other fields, except for the image field. It can only be updated from the /admin page, but not from the update-profile page.

This is my image field in the Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.DateField(default=datetime.date(1989, 12, 25))
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='Unspecified')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Braşov')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profilepics', blank=True)
```

Here is my ProfileForm:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('dob', 'gender', 'city', 'image')
```

This is the html template:

```
{% block body %}
<form method="post">
<div class="container">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ user_form.as_p }}
{{ profile_form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Update</button>
<a href="myprofile" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Cancel</a>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the update_profile view:

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('myprofile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'filter/updateprofile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

Thank you very much for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the attribute enctype to your form tag in your html document `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

See this question 
[Django ModelForm Imagefield Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628979/django-modelform-imagefield-upload)

And as is documented in w3schools
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp